# How to extract required data from file, line by line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file abc.txt with sample data as show below

```
Server.log_19September2020_14_31_11:09192020,143110457017,info,#PERFORMANCE:End:<1600506070>:<399767>:<1600506070>:<457014>
Server.log_19September2020_14_31_11:09192020,143110530373,info,#PERFORMANCE:End:<1600506070>:<457135>:<1600506070>:<530369>
Server.log_19September2020_14_31_11:09192020,143110603215,info,#PERFORMANCE:End:<1600506070>:<530506>:<1600506070>:<603211>
```

Here I want to extract the last 4 data i.e. < d1 >:< d2 >:< d3 >:< d4 > from each line and store it in 4 different variables.
How do I extract these 4 required data from file while file reading ?

Comment: So, the variables should only have the values of the current line?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace()` and `rsplit()`.
Data is in this format `< d1 >:< d2 >:< d3 >:< d4 >` each variable is inside this symbol `<>` and separated by `:` so. I first replace `<` and `>` with empty string(`''`). After replace data should look like this `d1:d2:d3:d4` now you can simply use `rsplit(':', 4)` to extract those data.

```
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        _, d1, d2, d3, d4 = line.strip().replace('<', '').replace('>', '').rsplit(':', 4)
        print(d1, d2, d3, d4)
```

**Output:**

```
1600506070 399767 1600506070 457014
1600506070 457135 1600506070 530369
1600506070 530506 1600506070 603211
```

Comment: This worked. Can you provide some explanation for this. As in when you split with ':' why didnt it not fetch the data around the initial ':' in the line

Comment: @SumaiyaA what do you mean by initial?

Comment: Basically can you explain what you did here. Why replace and then split?

Answer (score 2):

See [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader) standard module example (changed delimiter):

```py
with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=':')
    for row in spamreader:
        print([n[1:-1] for n in row[-4:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re` module `re.search` method, since you know the pattern of the data you're looking for

```py
import re
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    m = re.search(r"<(\d+)>:<(\d+)>:<(\d+)>:<(\d+)>", line)
    d1, d2, d3, d4 = m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4)
    print(d1, d2, d3, d4)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: I copy-pasted the first line: `Server.log_19September2020_14_31_11:09192020,143110457017,info,#PERFORMANCE:End:<1600506070>:<399767>:<1600506070>:<457014>` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regex**

```
import re
from operator import itemgetter

filename = open("abc.txt", 'r')
read_file = filename.readlines()
for each_line in read_file:
    a, b, c, d = itemgetter(0,1,2,3)(re.findall("<[0-9]*>", each_line))
    print a, b, c, d
```

Output

```
<1600506070> <399767> <1600506070> <457014>
<1600506070> <457135> <1600506070> <530369>
<1600506070> <530506> <1600506070> <603211>
```